# tomcat configuration issue sever.xml

Tags: tomcat, configuration

Hi i have an issue configuring my tomcat 
on my localhost (windows ) i can add on the server.xml or on root.xml the following

```
<Context docBase="appName/dist/" path="/" reloadable="true" />
```

And it will work where appName is the application name and the dist is a folder inside 
When i deploy it to a linux server and restart the service it fails 
and will only work with out the folder name 
and this is not what i am looking for 
i also have in my web.xml the welcome file to go to

Answer (score 0):

First, do not put `<Context>` elements in `server.xml`. Instead, put them in your web application's `META-INF/context.xml` file. Then you won't need to have the `path` attribute which you have set incorrectly above. The path for the "root" web application needs to be an empty string, not `/`.

Second, the root web application's deployment descriptor needs to be called `ROOT.xml` if you put it into `CATALINA_BASE/conf/[engine]/[host]/` (case is important, even on case-insensitive filesystems like NTFS).

Finally, remove the trailing `/` from the `docBase` attribute. It shouldn't matter, but it's not correct to have that trailing slash like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply in the linux server i entered "" for the root Seasoned i also added the ROOT.XML but it didn't solved the issue

Comment: Where is your WAR file (or exploded directory) and where is your `ROOT.xml` file (make sure to use `ROOT.xml` -- case matters).

Comment: Its under webapps , i tried the ROOT.xml under the localhost as well no luck yet

Comment: So you have `CATALINA_BASE/webapps/appName/dist` which contains your web application? It's generally a problem to have your manually-deployed web application sitting under the `CATALINA_BASE/webapps` directory. Try moving it somewhere else, at least temporarily, and adjusting your `docBase` to use a fully-qualified path. Also, remove the `path` attribute entirely from your `<Context>`: Tomcat will detect the deployment path from the name of the file (`ROOT`, in this case, which is special and means "/" to Tomcat).